# Why does sublime shows "Unable to find target command: exec" after building?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've installed sublime text 2 on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. But no matter which build system i choose, after i press "ctrl+b", the console will shows "Unable to find target command: exec". But i can run exec in the terminal.
So how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out to be that the package have been corrupted. I don't know the details, but finally i just delete and reinstall Sublime, everything goes well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any modifications to Subl since installing? Anything on the command line might have caused the issue.

Try to quit sublime and open it back up. That might help also.